# complicated left Join query ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, join

I'm trying to combine a left join query to retrieve data in ruby on rails, it's a little bit complicated cause I have 3 table related:

```
#User
has_many   :work_contracts, -> { order 'start_on DESC' }
has_many   :work_contract_types, through: :work_contracts

#WorkContract
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :work_contract_type

#WorkContractType
```

I need to retrieve all user even who's have a nil contract type.

can some one here give an example that use this kind of query to understand more about joins queries in ruby on rails ? Thanks.

Comment: Try the following: `User.joins('left join work_contracts wc on wc.user_id = users.id').joins('left join work_contract_types wct on wct.work_contract_id = wct.id')` (basically, use `left join` instead of `inner join` if you want to keep records that may not exists for the row they are joined to)

Comment: Also, this looks like you are trying to fetch _any User having at least one `work_contract`_. Is that correct? If so, then a simple `User.joins(:work_contracts)` should work

Comment: Thanks @MrYoshiji for your comment ; I tried the first one and I got this error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" WHERE (public.users.type != 'Superadmin') AND ((((UNACCENT(""
LINE 1: ...ract.work_contract_type_id = work_contract_type.id" WHERE (p...